# How to Print remainders of a number(userInput) when divide by 2 at each iteration

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to print remainder of a number(userInput) when divide by 2 at each iteration in Python.
I have similar code in C look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    int i;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&i);

    for(i=i; i <= 1000; i = i/2){
        if (i==0){
            break;
        }
        printf("%d\n",i%2);

    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Try to be more clear. What exactly are you trying to achieve? the C code you posted divides the number each time by 2 and then gets the reminder of the result. For example - if the user input is 56, it will print: (56%2) -> 0, (28%2) -> 0, (14%2) -> 0 (7%2) -> 1 .. and so on.

Comment: Yes, Can I use same logic in python. I tried to but it looks like not possible. I have same code in JAVA like this:                                                                                                                                public class Number{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        for ( int i =64; i <= 64; i = i/2){
            if (i==0){
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(i%2);
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
user_number = int(input('Please enter a number\n'))

while (user_number > 1):
    print('{}%2 = {}'.format(user_number, user_number % 2))
    user_number = user_number / 2
```

Please correct me if I misunderstood the purpose of the code.

Comment: I would suggest a while loop in your C code as well. As you can see I also added a friendly print.

Comment: Yes, I will surely try.